# Optimization of a mapreduce code (reduce side join)

Tags: java, optimization, hadoop, mapreduce

I need your help for optimizing my code of map.
I use the design pattern of reduce side join in the book MapReduce Design Pattern. All works but I try to improve the code to not duplicate the key join during the joining.

Actually the key join is in the value in the second table, so I want to remove it. It's why, I split my value and try to remove the first element. But I think this method is not the better and cost a lot.

This is my mapper class :

```
public class MapTable2 extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

private Text outKey = new Text();
private Text outValue = new Text();
private String tab[];
private List<String> list;
private String tmp ="";

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    tab = value.toString().split(";");
    list = Arrays.asList(tab);
    outKey.set(list.get(0).trim());
    list.remove(0);
    for (String val : list) {
        tmp = tmp+val;
    }
    outValue.set("B" + tmp);
    context.write(outKey, outValue);
}
```

}

The original code was :

```
public class MapTable2 extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{

private Text outKey = new Text();
private Text outValue = new Text();
private String tab[] ;

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{


    tab = value.toString().split(";");
    outKey.set(tab[0].trim());
    outValue.set("B" + value.toString()); // outValue = outKey + value
    context.write(outKey, outValue);
}
```

}

Have you got some advices to improve my code ?

Thanks in advance.
Angelik

Comment: If you have working code but would like suggestions on how to improve, [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to post this

Comment: I didn't know, thanks for the information !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to split string into two parts:

```
String[] parts = value.toString().split(";", 2);
outKey.set(parts[0].trim());
outValue.set("B" + parts[1]);
```

Comment: Yes of course ! Thank you Alexey. I must be too tired to not thinking about this kind of solution ! Thanks !!!